# Continuity of a function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, continuity

Let $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ with compact suppport and $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Is the following function continuous  for $z\in Q = \{ z : \Re z\in [a,b], \Im \sqrt{z} \in (0,1] \}$:
$$ F(z)=\bigg(\alpha-i\frac{\sqrt{z}}{4\pi}\bigg)^{-1}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}dx\bigg( f(x)\frac{e^{i\sqrt{z}|x|}}{4\pi|x|}\bigg)$$
? I have  tried to evaluate 
$$F(z)-F(z')$$ using the theorem  of dominated convergence.

Comment: If you want braces to display, you need two backslashes like \\{ or use \lbrace and \rbrace (I changed this). I left the 'lonely' bracket in the display as it was not clear what you intended. 

Comment: For the integral to be well-defined, what is the behavior of $f(x)$ near $x=0$? Or, is the differential operator $d$ applied to the whole thing? 

Comment: I've modified the question!Is it clear now?

Comment: The integral is well defined thanks to the Schwartz inequality